# Flask-session not working when I use flask-flash

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

H!

I am trying to do a simple login and logout method, that greets you with a `flash()` when you do it. but for some reason, the session.pop() does nothing when I try to logout and use the flash.

```py
@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.pop("_usern", None) #For some reason I don't understand it does not pop _usern if I use flash. 
    flash("Goodbye!", 'info')
    return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

I did noticed that after using flash() the debugger returns `<FileSystemSession {'_flashes': [('info', 'Goodbye!')]}>` instead of `<FileSystemSession {'_usern': '******'}>` as value in session.pop()

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `session.clear()` instead. And also make sure your code that checks whether the user is logged in or not run correctly.